# Unable to add peers through bootnode

Tags: private-blockchain, bootnodes

I have created three nodes on a private ethereum blockchain passing a unique networkid flag along with usage of the same genesis file .

Now two of them are running on remote machine , and one on my local system. **The issue i am facing is i am able to add the remote nodes as peers when i use the admin.addPeer command on the geth console , but not when i am using bootstrap nodes** -

geth --bootnodes enodeRemotePeer1,enodeRemotePeer2 --datadir local --rpc --rpcport 8001 --rpcapi "eth,web3,miner" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --port 8002 console

Comment: are you using enode URI notation ? or what is enodeRemotePeer1, a host name?